# App crashes while executing showStudents() function

Tags: c, function, crash

```
#include <stdio.h>


    int count = 0;//global


struct student{

    char name[20];
    char surname[20];
    int age;
    char registrationDate[10];      
} v[200];





void addStudents(){


    printf("\nJu po shtoni nje student te ri ne liste!\n");

    printf("\nShkruani emrin:");
    scanf("%s", &v[count].name);

    printf("\nShkruani mbiemrin:");
    scanf("%s", &v[count].surname);

    printf("\nShkruani daten e regjistrimit:");
    scanf("%s", &v[count].registrationDate);

    printf("\nShkruani moshen:");
    scanf("%d", &v[count].age);

    printf("\nRegjistrimi u ruajt me sukses.\n");
    count ++;
    return;


}


void menu (){



        printf("\nShtyp 1 per te shtuar student.");
        printf("\nShtyp 2 per te shfaqur studentet.");
        printf("\nShtyp 3 per menune.");
        printf("\nShtyp 0 per te mbyllur programin.");

        return;
}

void showStudents(){


    int i = 0;
    for(i=0; i<=count; i++){
        printf("Emri i studentit te: %d: %s\n", i+1, v[i].name);

        printf("Mbiemri i studentit te: %d: %s\n", i+1, v[i].surname);

        printf("Data e regjistrimit i studentit te: %d: %s\n", i+1, v[i].registrationDate);

        printf("Mosha i studentit te: %d: %s\n", i+1, v[i].age);


    }

    return;
}


main(){ 

    printf("*******************PROGRAM PER LIBRARI NE GJUHEN C***********************\n\n");

    menu();
        bool cond = true;

        while(cond){

        int choice;
            printf("\n\nShkruani zgjedhjen tuaj: ");
            scanf("%d", &choice);

        switch(choice){
            case 1:
                addStudents();
            break;

            case 2:
                showStudents();
            break;

            case 3:
                menu();
            break;
            case 0:
                cond = false;

        }


    }

}
```

I just don't know the reason why it keeps crashing. It prints out the first student data and than crashes. So if I add more than 1 student it will print out the data for the first and not for the others because of crashing. I'm adding students with the addStudents() function and printing their data with showStudent(). Any sugesstion?

Comment: If you have an array of `count` elements, what is the last valid index in that array? In your loop in `showStudents` what is the last index you will use?

Comment: In the loop: `for(i=0; i<=count; i++){` you should go to `i<count`

Comment: I was trying different versions, so I forgot to change it when I copied it from the IDE. That was not the problem. The problem was: (printf("Mosha i studentit te: %d: %s\n", i+1, v[i].age);) in that line. v[i].age is an int. It crashes when complier tries to show it as a string.